# How to address the 2 logical qubits on the toric code individually? In general, how to address $k$ logical qubits in a $[[n,k,d]]$ code independently?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, toric-code

Suppose I have a $[[n,k,d]]$-quantum error correction code. Let us take the toric code $(T^2=S^1 \times S^1)$ as an example. We have 2 logical qubits whose logical operators lie along the different circles $S^1$. How do we engineer interactions that manipulate only one of the degrees of freedom or distinguish them as target and control? For example, how do we implement $U$ such that $U:|00\rangle\mapsto|10\rangle$ and CNOT such that CNOT: $|10\rangle\mapsto|11\rangle$?